# Наезд блоков друг на друга в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Попробовал сегодня впервые bootstrap. И сразу впал в недоумение. При уменьшении размеров экрана колонки с классами `col-xs-*` наезжают друг на друга, текст и картинки из соседних дивов в одном ряду перекрывают друг друга, `padding` и `margin` игнорируются.

Для полного исправления ситуации приходится ставить для `col-xs-*` `display:inline-table` либо `display:table`. Это так и должно быть? Или я чего-то не так подключил?

Вот пример:

```css
.container {
    width: 320px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Текст Текст </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот исходный файл:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Project css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt=""></div>
<div class="col-xs-1">Текст Текст </div>
<div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
<div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- JavaScript section -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На экране мобильного слово в колонке может оказаться шире самой колонки. Тогда оно выйдет за края колонки и будет казаться, что колонки наползли друг на друга.

Есть два типовых способа этого избежать:

1. уменьшать размер шрифта с помощью [медиа-запросов](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries);
2. [Перестраивать сетку](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed), чтобы на экране мобильного колонки занимали больше условных столбцов — не один-два, а шесть или все двенадцать.

А чтобы картинки не выходили за пределы колонки, в бутстрапе предусмотрен [специальный класс `.img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive). Он задаёт картинке три свойства:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
```

```css
.set-font-size {
   font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .set-font-size {
     font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row set-font-size">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый первый.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй второй.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Глеб! Добавлять .image-responsive действительно проще, чем править css. Что касается добавления колонок до 12. То, протестировал, это не помогло (с текстом). Так что остается изменение шрифта (спасибо за пример реализации). Или перевод divov в табличный display.

Comment: @НиколайВанин А как вы добавляли до 12? Бутстрап помогает назначать колонкам разную долю от ширины экрана в зависимости от разрешения. Например, если дать колонке класс `col-xs-12 col-sm-6`, то на мобильном она займёт всю ширину экрана, а на экранах шире 768 пикселей - половину от ширины экрана.

Comment: Глеб, я добавил колонки col-xs-1 col-xs-3 col-xs-8. В сумме они дали 12.

Comment: Надо по другому. `col-xs-1` на мобильном - слишком мало, чтобы вмещать любой текст. Задайте колонкам разные классы для разных размеров экрана. Нажмите в примере из моего ответе `На весь экран". Первые две колонки на мобильном занимают половину экрана, а на десктопе - четверть. А последняя на десктопе оказывается справа, а на мобильном - внизу.

Comment: Не сразу понял основную логику работы с колонками bootstrap. На малых экранах мы не уменьшаем (как я сначала подумал), а наоборот увеличиваем общее кол-во колонок (чтобы расположить их в несколько рядов). Теперь, благодаря Вашему примеру, дошло. Спасибо, Глеб.

Comment: Понял почему, в вашем примере нет наезда текста. Колонка достаточно широкая, чтобы любые слова в нее помещались и переносились на другую строку. Значит в режиме display:block текст остается в границах колонки,   если все слова по ширине помещаются в колонке или стоит (word-wrap: break-word) .

Comment: Да, всё верно. Чтобы текст было удобно читать на узком экране, мы отдаём колонке больше условных столбцов.

Comment: ОК. Решено. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего никуда не наезжает, см. сниппет. Возможно, вы не ограничили максимальный размер изображения.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.  max-width: 100%; Действительно убирает наезд на изображение. Но если картинку заменить текстом, наезд (уже на первую колонку текста) возобновляется.

Comment: Покажите это в сниппете

Comment: Вот скриншот: https://yadi.sk/i/LpIBTrYu3KwG72

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, вопрос должен содержать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Я сделал это за вас. Скопируйте мой сниппет, вставьте его в свой вопрос и покажите проблему.

Comment: Извините, я чего-то не знаю как его вставить в комментарии: Получается слитный текст: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">Текст Текст</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Текст Текст </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: Вам надо откорректировать свой вопрос, добавив туда текст сниппета. Нажмите "править" под текстом вопроса, потом кнопку - "фрагмент кода" в строке форматирования.

Comment: Отредактировал (заменил картинку на "Текст Текст"). Буквы второго столбца залезают на буквы первого.

Comment: Я не вижу ваш сниппет в тексте вашего вопроса. ОК, сейчас сам вставлю туда свой сниппет - редактируйте.

Comment: Вставил, редактируйте.

Comment: Здесь при запуске кода не налезает. А у меня в хроме налезает почему-то...

Comment: А вот именно потому сообщество и требует минимальный самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. У вас проблема явно в той части, которая не приведена в вопросе - а именно, в вашем styles.css. Смотрите в инспекторе браузера, почему в вычисленных свойствах у вас что-то не так.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что мой файл css пуст. Работает только файл css bootstrap...

Comment: Ширина первой колонки в инспекторе  width: 8.33333333% (текст в нее не помещается), ссылка на 1649 строку файла bootstrap.css а две другие 25%. Мой собственный css файл пуст. Хотя width: 8.33333333% строка не 1649, а 1646.

Comment: на какой ширине экрана смотрите?

Comment: Я исправил "ваш" сниппет в вашем вопросе - поставил "ширину экрана" в 320px. Да, текст наезжает друг на друга. А чего вы хотели? он просто не помещается в ширину колонки. Надо уменьшать размер шрифта на узких экранах.

Comment: Понятно, надо уменьшать шрифты. Спасибо. Мне как раз и надо было узнать стандартное решение. Ставить ли display: table или что-то еще делают.

Comment: Нет, обычно уменьшают шрифты, padding, margin у элементов. В общем, там процесс творческий.